# Calculator program

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type

The code evaluates the value of a math expression in a variable stored in a string. The code works, but I encountered an error that made me wonder why.

Without `!` the code below gives an error warning saying the optional Int is unwrapped.

```
let operands : [Int]  = [Int(split_exp[0])!, Int(split_exp[2])!]
```

**Note:** This line is the 3rd line

Why does this error occur without the `!` ?

```
// string calculator app. x = multiplication

let expression = "2 x 2"

let split_exp =  expression.components(separatedBy: " ")

let operands : [Int]  = [Int(split_exp[0])!, Int(split_exp[2])!]
let operation = split_exp[1] // get the operands and the operation

switch operation {
case "+":
    print("\(operands[0]) + \(operands[1]) = \(operands.reduce(0, +))")
case "x":
    print("\(operands[0]) x \(operands[1]) = \(operands.reduce(1, *))")

default:
    print("No answer ")
}
```

Comment: The reason for the ! point is because split_exp is an optional (nullable).  As expression.components() could return nil.  So the ! is an implicit unwrapping.  It will still throw an exception if indeed split_exp is nil or there are not 3 items in the array.

Comment: @LorenRogers Incorrect. The `Int` initializer that takes a `String` is failable. This has nothing to do with `split_exp` which can't be `nil` here.

Comment: Yeah I see it now.  split_exp[0] could be == "hello", and thus Int() would fail.  I didn't notice the Int().

Answer (score 0):

The `!` operator forces the `Int(myString)` to **unwrapp**.

I suppose you are new to swift and should read a bit about **Optionals** in Swift. Here is a link for you to understand more about it :

https://medium.com/@agoiabeladeyemi/optionals-in-swift-2b141f12f870

---

To sum it up briefly, an Optional value is a value that may be `nil` ( aka `null` if you comes from another language ). This is a way to wrap value that you are not sure that they are defined or not.

In your example, casting a `String` to an `Int` via `Int( String )` can return `nil`

e.g. :

`Int("5")` returns `5`

`Int("r")` returns `nil`

by adding `!` at the end of the command, you basically say to the program "I am 100% sure that this cast will not fail, and return an `Int`". This is a way to avoid having to deal with optional values when you are sure that they will not be nil.

Please not that if it fails, for instance `Int("q")!` (would return nil), the program **crashes**

Answer (score 0):

`Int(String)` [returns an optional Int](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int#2891078) since not every string can be converted to integer. By putting exclamation sign at the end you say "throw an exception if you can't convert my input to integer"

Here is a good article about "Optionals" in Swift: https://hackernoon.com/swift-optionals-explained-simply-e109a4297298